# Pinch zoom open google search application on nexus7

Tags: android, scaling

Hello I am creating an application for scaling and moving a image .And my application working fine on all mobile devices include nexus 4 and nexus 5 but when i test my app in nexus 7 multitouch will open google search application .And not behave in right way. Please check in following video.

http://youtu.be/_4ic40xfNZk

Please let me know how i resolve this application 
Thanks for any help.